How to view outlook email images in Python tkinter screen
I have an issue with embedded email images. Their borders come into the tkinter frame the right size and position as they do in Outlook, but only as broken links, and no image. Some images come in if they are fully html, like an email from mailchimp or similar news letter style, but a simple image placed inside the body of a normal email, or an image in an outlook signature, do not show.
I appreciate any help.
This is what I have so far:
import sys
import os
import tempfile
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QListWidget, QListWidgetItem, QDialog
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
import win32com.client
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import base64

# Function to fetch emails from Outlook
def fetch_emails():
    try:
        outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
        inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)  # 6 refers to the inbox folder
        messages = inbox.Items
        messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)

        emails = []
        for i in range(min(10, len(messages))):  # Fetching last 10 emails
            message = messages[i]
            try:
                # Check if HTMLBody is available and not empty
                if hasattr(message, 'HTMLBody') and message.HTMLBody:
                    html_body = str(message.HTMLBody)  # Convert HTMLBody to string
                    inline_images = save_inline_images(message)
                    html_body = replace_inline_images(html_body, inline_images)

                    emails.append({
                        'subject': message.Subject,
                        'html_body': html_body,
                        'datetime_received': message.ReceivedTime,
                    })
                else:
                    emails.append({
                        'subject': message.Subject,
                        'html_body': '<p>This email does not contain HTML content.</p>',
                        'datetime_received': message.ReceivedTime,
                    })
                    print(f"Email {i} ('{message.Subject}') does not have an HTMLBody.")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"An error occurred while accessing email {i} ('{message.Subject}'): {e}")
                continue
        return emails
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return []

# Function to save inline images from an email
def save_inline_images(message):
    inline_images = {}
    attachments = message.Attachments

    for attachment in attachments:
        if attachment.Type == 6:  # Type 6 refers to inline images
            cid = attachment.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F")
            file_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, attachment.FileName)
            attachment.SaveAsFile(file_path)
            with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
                image_data = f.read()
                encoded_image = base64.b64encode(image_data).decode("utf-8")
            inline_images[cid] = encoded_image

    return inline_images

# Function to replace inline images in the HTML content
def replace_inline_images(html_body, inline_images):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_body, 'html.parser')

    for img in soup.find_all('img'):
        src = img.get('src', '')
        if src.startswith('cid:'):
            cid = src[4:]
            if cid in inline_images:
                img['src'] = f"data:image/jpeg;base64,{inline_images[cid]}"

    return str(soup)

class EmailViewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Outlook Email Viewer")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

        # Main layout
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_widget = QWidget()
        main_widget.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(main_widget)

        # Email list
        self.email_list = QListWidget()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.email_list)

        # Fetch and display emails
        self.emails = fetch_emails()
        if not self.emails:
            self.email_list.addItem(QListWidgetItem("No emails to display"))

        for email in self.emails:
            item = QListWidgetItem(f"{email['subject']} ({email['datetime_received']})")
            self.email_list.addItem(item)

        # Connect list item click to email display
        self.email_list.itemClicked.connect(self.open_email_viewer)

    def open_email_viewer(self, item):
        index = self.email_list.row(item)
        email = self.emails[index]

        # Create a new window to display the email
        self.email_window = QDialog(self)
        self.email_window.setWindowTitle(email['subject'])
        self.email_window.setGeometry(150, 150, 800, 600)

        # Layout for the new window
        email_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.email_window.setLayout(email_layout)

        # QWebEngineView to display the email content
        email_viewer = QWebEngineView()
        email_layout.addWidget(email_viewer)
        email_viewer.setHtml(email['html_body'])

        self.email_window.exec()

# Run the application
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    viewer = EmailViewer()
    viewer.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

I've tried so many different recommendations to fix this, but none of them seem to get the images to show up. Anything other than what I have, has so far only made it worse. The code I provided has been the closest to actually viewing an email like you can in Outlook. I have also noticed that emails that have no HTML just show up in this viewer with a note that says there is no html available.
Long story short, I just need to be able to view any/all emails as if they were opened in Outlook.

why do you ask for tkinter if you use PyQt6?

The rest of my program is based off of tkinter. This is just a small piece to a larger program. I did have this set up with tkinter before, but it was one of the recommended ideas to work around the issue I am having with it.
I am also trying to see if I can change it so I print a PDF of the email and then view the PDF in the window as well, and I’m not doing so good there either.
Again, my goal is to view the email within a program window and any way is fine if I can get it to work with images.
